# Create a component for the palette

Tags: c#, components, controls

I have never created a component before, but now have a few which are basically .cs files. They are of type System.Windows.Forms.Control.

But they are only available on the control palette when I am using the solution they are part of. It makes use of a few images which are in the /Resources folder.

Is there a way to make the component into a DLL, so that I can use it in any project by simply referencing it? Or else, make it into a component that always appears in my palette?

Comment: BTW, it's called the _toolbox_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Control Library project, which is a Class Library (DLL) that contains public classes that inherit `Control`.

You can then add a reference to the compiled DLL (or to the project if it's in the same solution) and the controls will appear in your toolbox.